# Ionic2 ios - trying to scroll one view scrolls a different view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this strange issue only when using iOS (actually haven't tried Android, but windows works fine).

So I'm using Ionic2 with tabs. 2 of the tabs are basically just showing data that I'm pulling in from an API. When the first tab loads, I can scroll up and down perfectly fine. I switch to the next tab/view and that also loads and scrolls fine. Now I try to go back to the previous tab, and scrolling appears to be frozen. While the console showed absolutely no errors, I quickly found out that not only is this scrolling frozen, but it is actually scrolling the tab that I had just switched from instead (I see this by switching back to the previous tab and notice it scrolling from momentum).

I have captured this issue on a screen recording of my simulator here: https://youtu.be/8yKSf9m10W4

Again, works fine when doing "ionic serve". Issue only exists on iOS.

This is the code for the view that is getting stuck (Events)

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Events
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content padding class="events">
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let event of events">
          <ion-card>
              <ion-card-content>
                 {{event.startDayWeek}}, {{event.startMonth}} {{event.startDay}}th, {{event.startYear}}
              </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

This below is the Podcast view that scrolls in the background. Its pretty much the same as the other, only its using the ionic-audio plugin.

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>podcast</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="podcast">
    <ion-list>
        <audio-track #audio *ngFor="let podcast of podcasts"  [track]="podcast" (onFinish)="onTrackFinished($event)">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail item-left>
              <audio-track-play dark [audioTrack]="audio"><ion-spinner></ion-spinner></audio-track-play>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <div item-content style="width:100%">
              <!-- <p><strong>{{podcast.title}}</strong> &#x26AC; <em>{{podcast.description}}</em></p> -->
              <audio-track-progress-bar duration progress [audioTrack]="audio"></audio-track-progress-bar>
              <em style="font-size:.5em">Track ID: {{audio.id}}</em>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
        </audio-track>
      </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Can you give more details on how you set up the tabs?

Comment: Yea I have a tabs.ts controller which assigns each page to a corresponding root on the tabs.html view.  Edit: here is a quick github repo I spun up with my app files https://github.com/tjohnson5/Trav-Ionic2-App1